# Redacting capture group values

Tags: regex, powershell, redaction

Using REGEX to find patterns in a capture group; now I need to replace/redact the values found.

trying to replace values in a fixed length field:
REGEX to search: `(\d{10})(.{20}) (.+)`.

The string is:

```
01234567890Alice Stone          3978 Smith st...
```

I have to replace capture group 2 (full name) with X's (or better yet just the first and last name in the capture group 2)

Regex: `(\d{10})(.{20})(.+)`

replace value `$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$3`

This works, but thought there would be a more glamorous solution (Maybe like `$1 x{20} $3`)  or even better somehow just redact values with letters in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to formulate a replacement string whose length should match a - potentially variable-length - substring of the input string, you need to calculate the replacement string *dynamically*, via a *script block* (delegate).

In PowerShell *Core* you can now pass a script block directly as the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375)'s replacement operand:

```
PS> '01234567890Alice Stone          3978 Smith st...' -replace 
      '(?<=^\d{10}).{20}', { 'x' * $_.Value.Length }

0123456789xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  3978 Smith st...
```

- `'(?<=^\d{10}` is a positive look-behind assertion that matches the first 10 digits without capturing them, and `.{20}` matches and captures the next 20 characters.
- The script block is called for each match with `$_` containing the match at hand as a [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance; `.Value` contains the matched text.
- Thus, `'x' * $_.Value.Length` returns a string of `x` chars. of the same length as the match.

---

In *Windows PowerShell* you have to use the [`[regex]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) directly:

```
PS> [regex]::Replace('01234567890Alice Stone          3978 Smith st...',
      '(?<=^\d{10}).{20}', { param($m) 'x' * $m.Value.Length })

0123456789xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  3978 Smith st...
```

---

If the length of the substring to replace is *known in advance* - as in your case - you could more simply do:

```
PS> $len = 20; '01234567890Alice Stone          3978 Smith st...' -replace 
      "(?<=^\d{10}).{$len}", ('x' * $len)

0123456789xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  3978 Smith st...
```

---

Unconditionally *redacting all letters* is even simpler:

```
PS> '01234567890Alice Stone          3978 Smith st...' -replace '\p{L}', 'x'

01234567890xxxxx xxxxx          3978 xxxxx xx...
```

`\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter.

---

*Redacting the letters only in the matching substring* requires nesting a `-replace` operation:

```
PS> '01234567890Alice Stone          3978 Smith st...' -replace 
      '(?<=^\d{10}).{20}', { $_ -replace '\p{L}', 'x' }

01234567890xxxxx xxxxx          3978 Smith st...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this expression would be an option:

```
([0-9]{11}).+?(\s*[0-9].+)
```

and the replacement would be:

```
$1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$2
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RAHxZT/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/RAHxZT/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$oldstr = "0123456789Alice Stone 3978 Smith st..."
[regex]$r = '(\d{10})(.{20})(.+)'

$newstr = $r.Replace($data,'$1'+'x'*20+'$3')
```

Here, the 'x' character is multiplied by 20 (effectively repeated 20 times).

> 0123456789xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxth st...

As others have shown, capture group 2 isn't required, so it can be simplified to:

```
[regex]$r = '(\d{10}).{20}(.+)'

$newstr = $r.Replace($data,'$1'+'x'*20+'$2')
```